# Getting permission to access users music favorites

Tags: facebook-graph-api, permissions, facebook-php-sdk, favorites

We need to get the music favorites from users account through our App using PHP SDK, but calling `$facebook->api('/' . $facebookUser['id'] . '/music', 'get')` only retrieves the information if the user has changed the permissions for the music favorites to Public.

Is there a way to ask the user for special permission to access their favorites even thought they haven't set those permissions to Public?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `user_likes` or `friends_likes` permission to get this.

If it is not set to public, you need to also have a user `access_token` from a user who can see this information.

If you are trying to circumvent a user's privacy options, that is a good way to get your app banned.